# laravel format() function working for some blades only

Tags: php, laravel

I am damn confused about the `format()` function of laravel.In some blade `format()` works fine.But in user.blade works only when I add following function

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'last_login_at');
}
```

user.blade

```
<td>{{ $user->created_at->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
```

and in my activity blade not working even `getDates()` function added.what's the reason behind that? Thanks in advance.

> Error =Call to a member function format() on string (View:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\odata\resources\views\activity\list.blade.php)

Comment: What error you are getting ? where is format function ? Where you are adding `getDates` ?

Comment: I update my question. Please review the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is giving you error because `format()` is function of Carbon.

Use below code in your blade.

```
 {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

To know more about Carbon visit http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/.

Comment: ok its solved . Buy Why do not showing an errors on other blade files?

Comment: other blade file might get dates as Carbon object so format() function can be called directly without converting it to Carbon Object

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override `getDates()` function. Just add columns to a `$dates` variable:

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'last_login_at'];
```

When you're doing this, Laravel will create Carbon instance for these dates, so you'll be able to use `format()` and other funtions.

Comment: I add your code to my user.blade and remove getDates.its done.but in my other blade there is no getDates or $dates thn too its working how? and still showing the Error =Call to a member function format() on string  for the activity blade.

Comment: @Alfizamalek you shouldn't add it to a view, you should add it to a model. When you see the error, that means Laravel didn't parsed date with Carbon. It does it automatically only for `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.